# Simple query taking 160+ seconds on android device when it takes 0.2 seconds from Unity3d editor

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

```
var coll = await _firestore
   .Collection("Collection")
   .Document("RsthH7NhZoNVBMG4g979")
   .GetSnapshotAsync();
```

this simple query take 160+ seconds to execute on android device.
And it is working fine from Unity3d editor (PC) taking only 0.2 seconds to execute.

I try to load collection that contain one document with list of 200 simple elements total size 8KB.
And it load to long.